# Cannot find files in WORKDIR of docker image

Tags: linux, docker, nextflow

I've created a docker image using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR /usr/local/src

# Setting up general environment
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get install -y hmmer \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## Installing miniconda
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH

# Installing NLRTracker
RUN git clone https://github.com/eliza-m/NLRexpress 
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/NLRexpress

# Setting up the conda environment and required variables 
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml && \
    conda init bash && \
    echo "conda activate nlrexpress" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/nlrexpress/bin:/usr/local/src/NLRexpress:$PATH
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV nlrexpress

RUN wget https://nlrexpress.biochim.ro/datasets/models.tar.gz && \
    tar -xf models.tar.gz && \
    rm models.tar.gz

RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n python nlrexpress.py" > nlrexpress && \
    chmod +x nlrexpress
```

I avoided using the `CMD` argument and made an executable `nlrexpress` because I want to use this image for `hmmsearch` too.

The image builds fine, and when i tested `docker run nlrexpress:latest nlrexpress` I get the expected output:

```
Usage: nlrexpress.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'nlrexpress.py --help' for help.

Error: Missing option '--input'.
```

However, when I use the container with nextflow I get the following error: `python: can't open file '/path/to/workDir/ea/72bd9e660d0ce79944d8bdde3dd024/nlrexpress.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Here is the nextflow process:

```
process NLRexpress {
  tag "$sample_id"
  publishDir params.PlantDir
  maxForks 1
  container = 'dthorbur1990/nlrexpress:latest'
  executor = "local"

  input:
      tuple val(sample_id), path(peptides)

  output:
      path "*.short.output.txt" 

  script:
  """
  mkdir output
  nlrexpress \\
        --input ../${peptides} \\
        --outdir ./output \\
        --module ${params.NE_Modules}

  mv output/*.short.output.txt ./
  """
}
```

How can i ensure files in the containers `WORKDIR` are available when mounting a container? I've tried setting `ENV` variables, but this doesn't seem to work either. I thought because `WORKDIR` is set, that the image would always mount to the `WORKDIR` path and all the files would be available.

I've found I can just clone the repo into the nextflow working directory, but this isn't an ideal workaround as I would also have to download the models for each process. The same issue goes for the `models` directory i downloaded into the container.

**Edit: Just adding that `hmmsearch` works absolutely fine with nextflow and the container.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own wrapper script, like in your first example, is generally considered a cleaner and more flexible solution. Here's one way using the [continuumio/miniconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) image:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN git clone https://github.com/eliza-m/NLRexpress /opt/NLRexpress
WORKDIR /opt/NLRexpress

RUN conda update conda -y

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml \
    && conda clean --all -y

RUN conda install -c bioconda hmmer \
    && conda clean --all -y

ARG CONDA_ENV_NAME=nlrexpress
RUN echo "conda activate ${CONDA_ENV_NAME}" >> ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH "/opt/conda/envs/${CONDA_ENV_NAME}/bin:${PATH}"

ARG NLREXPRESS=/usr/local/bin/nlrexpress
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' >> "${NLREXPRESS}" \
    && echo 'python /opt/NLRexpress/nlrexpress.py "$@"' >> "${NLREXPRESS}" \
    && chmod +x "${NLREXPRESS}"

ARG SPLITFASTA=/usr/local/bin/splitFasta
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' >> "${SPLITFASTA}" \
    && echo 'python /opt/NLRexpress/splitFasta.py "$@"' >> "${SPLITFASTA}" \
    && chmod +x "${SPLITFASTA}"

RUN wget https://nlrexpress.biochim.ro/datasets/models.tar.gz \
    && tar xf models.tar.gz \
    && rm models.tar.gz

CMD ["bash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting to grips with how docker works, but I found a solution in case anyone else has the same porblems.

First I tried to give the executable `nlrexpress` the full path to the python script:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n python /usr/local/src/NLRexpress/nlrexpress.py" > nlrexpress && \
    chmod +x nlrexpress
```

But this ended up executing the command and ignoring the input parameters that followed.

Instead, I indicated which binary was needed via the shebang so the python script itself could be executed without needed to write `python script.py`.

```
RUN sed  -i '1i #!/opt/conda/envs/nlrexpress/bin/python' nlrexpress.py && \
    chmod +x nlrexpress.py
```

Comment: Generally it's a better to use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead:  `RUN sed -i '1i #!/usr/bin/env python' nlrexpress.py && chmod +x nlrexpress.py`